# watermark is reset after blur

Tags: jquery, watermark

First, on page load, I set the default watermarks as follows:

```
function AddWatermarksDataEntry() {
    initialWatermarks = new Array();
    initialWatermarks.push(new Array("P1_BIRTHDATE_MASK", "__/__/____"));
    initialWatermarks.push(new Array("P2_BIRTHDATE_MASK", "__/__/____"));
    initialWatermarks.push(new Array("P1_VALIDFROM_MASK", "~#SF_DD/MM/YYYY~"));
    initialWatermarks.push(new Array("P2_VALIDFROM_MASK", "~#SF_DD/MM/YYYY~"));
    initialWatermarks.push(new Array("P1_IDENTITYDOCUMENTNUMBER", " "));
    initialWatermarks.push(new Array("P2_IDENTITYDOCUMENTNUMBER", " ")); //***-*******-**
    initialWatermarks.push(new Array("P1_VAT", "~#SF_9OR10_DIGIT~"));
    initialWatermarks.push(new Array("P2_VAT", "~#SF_9OR10_DIGIT~"));
    Watermarker(initialWatermarks);
}
```

Later on, when I adjust a dropdown value for my identity card type
I do the following:

```
if(newIdentityDocumentType == "1")
            {
                ChangeIdentityDocumentNumberField($('#'+ whichPerson +'_IDENTITYDOCUMENTNUMBER'), $('#'+ whichPerson +'_NATIONALITY'), watermarkIdentityDocumentNumberBelgian, foreignPersonWaterMark, 14, 14);
                $('#'+ whichPerson +'_IDENTITYDOCUMENTNUMBER').mask('999-9999999-99');
                $('.'+ whichPerson + '.identityDocumentNumber').text('e.g. 123-456789112-34');
            }
```

I check whether or not the user selected the correct identity document type. If he or she did, then change the properties of the input field, specifically, I would like the watermark to be adjusted.

The ChangeidentityDocumentField method calls the method that will change the watermark like this:

```
function ChangeIdentityDocumentNumberField(IdentityDocumentNumberField, NationalityField, WatermarkBelgian, WatermarkForeign, MaximumBelgian, MaximumForeign) {
    if (NationalityField.val() == "0") {
        //omitted code
        ChangeWatermark(IdentityDocumentNumberField, WatermarkBelgian);
    } else {
        //omitted code
        ChangeWatermark(IdentityDocumentNumberField, WatermarkForeign);
    }
}

function Watermarker(newWatermark) {
for (i = 0; i < newWatermark.length; i++) {
    $('#' + newWatermark[i][0]).Watermark(newWatermark[i][1]);

    $('#' + newWatermark[i][0]).blur(function (item, watermark) {
        return function () {
            //if ($('#' + item).val() == '') {
                $('#' + item).Watermark(watermark);

            //};
        };
    } (newWatermark[i][0], newWatermark[i][1]));
};
```

}

With this method lays, the problem, when I'm in an input field and I want to go out, the above function is called, everything goes well, I see that the watermark is added (when I'm debugging, but then, suddenly, when the code jumps to:

```
} (newWatermark[i][0], newWatermark[i][1]));
```

My watermark is reset to to the default value!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by removing the above code and replacing it with placeholder. But I've come across a new problem because of this:
[Change placeholder text with jquery also auto-update in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903620/change-placeholder-text-with-jquery-also-auto-update-in-ie)